# Twig doesn't show String with blank spaces

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

I have a problem with Twig.

I have an object that contains one attribute whose type is a String. The String contains some blank spaces  " ",(example "Prueba Primera"), but in the twig view when I show the text the view shows only "Prueba" the other part of the string doesn´t show. 
This is my object in php:

```
$informe->setTitulo("Prueba Primera");
```

This is my code in twig:

```
<input type = "text" name = "titulo"  id = "titulo" class = "texto"   value = {{informe.titulo}} disabled/>
```

And twig shows only : "Prueba"

Comment: Open HTML-source in browser and see that twig shows.

Comment: The HTML Source in browser shows this problem:<input type="text" name="titulo" id="titulo" class="texto" value="Nuevo" informe="" disabled="">

Comment: @CristianGomez. what problem? Your question states it only shows "Prueba" but that doesn't appear in that html?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add `"` around the twig value like that:

```
value="{{informe.titulo}}"
```